# Does updating a .deb installation create multiple installations instead of "updating"?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, update-manager, deb

I faced this scenario now with multiple programs:
I use to have shortcuts to start my applications. Visual Studio Code told me that there is an udpate available. I was redirected to their webpage and downloaded the .deb file. I double clicked it and let the package manager ("Ubtunu Software") install it.

Now, when I click on my shortcut, it seems to start the old version and gives me that update message again. When I use the unity search, I find 2 versions of the program. One that may be my shortcut and another one that seems to be the newer version (when I click it, the new version starts).

What's the reason for that? Was the package even updated at all, or did the package manager create a second installation instead of reusing the old and update it?

Comment: Simpler explanation: the package creators changed something in their layout, and didn't cleanup on package upgrading.

Comment: Yes it looks like the installation did create a second installation, which is valid and sometimes even desired to have different versions of a software. I think you have to update your shortcut to point to the new executable version.

Comment: @Thomas Man... Wtf. How can anyone find this a good idea? Why was this implemented like that in the first place? But thank you guys for the comments. This really annoys me a bit. Is there an easy way to uninstall the old installation?

Comment: Find the old version in your package manager of choice & uninstall it. Whoever created this released a new version/packagename, not an "update" to the old version.